# Xcopy: invalid number of parameters or file not found error

Tags: xcopy

From inside a .bat file, I m issuing this command

xcopy\s Folder1\folder2\folder3\blah-blah Folder1\temp\folder2\folder3

But I get the error:
The system cannot find the path specified.

I tried copying the same line to command line and tried it:
Then, I get the error, xcopys command not found.
If I try to use xcopy instead of xcopy/s, I get error:

File not found - Folder1folder2folder3blah-blah

If I use xcopy command with backward slash on command line: Invalid number of parameters.

I tried enclosing paths in quotes, but it does not help.
My file names don't have spaces in them but they do have -

I have checked the path of source and destination and they exist

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you're running under windows, so you have to use forward slashes for arguments.

`xcopy/s` is something very different from `xcopy\s`. The later searches for an application called `s` in a subfolder called `xcopy`. To further avoid confusion, separate the program from its argument(s) with spaces.